# CASE statement with SUM SQL

Tags: sql-server, case

Can someone help me out with the correct syntax for the below CASE statement please? It's part of a view I am creating where the Return Price is half the cost of the  calculated cost in the jobs table when the charge description has "Return" in it. its saying incorrect syntax the the keyword ELSE. Thanks in advance.

`

```
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[MMXREPORT]    Script Date: 11/08/2016 14:06:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Alter view [dbo].[MMXREPORT] AS
DECLARE @output int
SELECT isnull(Cus.CUSTOMERNUMBER,'') AS "ACCOUNT",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.DELDATEANDTIME,'') as "DELIVERY DATE" ,
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.JOBREFERENCE,'') AS "MMX REFERENCE",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.JOBNUMBER,'') AS "INDIGO REF",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.COLPOSTCODE,'') AS "COLLECTION POSTCODE",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.DELTOWN,'') AS "DELIVERY TOWN",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.DELLPOSTCODE,'') AS "DELIVERY POST CODE",
                 CASE when (select count (*) from jobcharge jobc inner join charge
                 on charge.chargeid = jobc.chargeid
                 where jobc.jobid = jobs.jobid and charge.description like '%return%') > 0 THEN 'YES'
                 ELSE 'NO' END as "RETURN AUTHORISED",
       isnull(dbo.GetClarionTime (DELREADYAT ),'') AS "PLANNED DELIVERY TIME",
       '' AS "DRIVER ARRIVAL TIME",
       '' AS "ENGINEER ARRIVAL TIME",
       isnull(convert(char(5), dbo.Jobs.PODDATEANDTIME, 108),'') AS"POD TIME",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.PODNAME,'') AS"POD NAME",
       isnull(dbo.Vehicle.VEHICLE,'') AS "VEHICLE SIZE",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.ACTUALMILEAGE,'0') AS "MILEAGE",
       isnull(dbo.Jobs.CALCULATEDCOST,'') AS "MILEAGE PRICE",

        SELECT @output = count (*) from jobcharge jobc inner join charge
        ON charge.chargeid = jobc.chargeid
        WHERE jobc.jobid = jobs.jobid AND charge.description LIKE '%return%'
        CASE WHEN @output > 0 THEN SUM(JOBS.CALCULATEDCOST/2)
        ELSE '0.00' END 
        AS "RETURN PRICE",         
       isnull((select sum (dbo.JobCharge.FLATRATE) from jobcharge inner join charge on charge.chargeid = jobcharge.chargeid
       WHERE dbo.Charge.DESCRIPTION like '%congestion%' and jobcharge.jobid = jobs.jobid),0) AS "CONGESTION CHARGE",

       '' AS "CONGESTION CHARGE COMMENTS",

       isnull((select sum (dbo.JobCharge.FLATRATE) from jobcharge inner join charge on charge.chargeid = jobcharge.chargeid
       WHERE dbo.Charge.DESCRIPTION like '%waiting time%' and jobcharge.jobid = jobs.jobid),0) AS "WAITING TIME CHARGE",

       '' AS "WAITING TIME COMMENTS",

       isnull((select sum (dbo.JobCharge.FLATRATE) from jobcharge inner join charge on charge.chargeid = jobcharge.chargeid 
       WHERE dbo.Charge.DESCRIPTION like '%hrs%' and jobcharge.jobid = jobs.jobid),0) AS "ANY OTHER CHARGES",


       '' AS "ANY OTHER COMMENTS",
       '' AS "TOTAL COST",JOBS.CUSTOMERID

FROM            dbo.Jobs left outer JOIN
                dbo.Vehicle ON dbo.Jobs.VEHICLEID = dbo.Vehicle.VEHICLEID left outer JOIN
              --  dbo.JobCharge ON dbo.Jobs.JobID = dbo.JobCharge.JOBID left outer JOIN
                dbo.Customer CUS ON dbo.Jobs.CUSTOMERID = CUS.CUSTOMERID
```

`
Above is the full query.

Comment: There'n no `FROM` in the `THEN SELECT` part. But it's hard to tell how to fix this because I don't know what you actually want.

Comment: Show the entire query

Comment: This is the full query.....

Comment: No, this is just a part of a larger statement.

Comment: In this query `jobs` not defined. Where's she ?

Comment: I can't seem to add the full query, it only allows me 600 characters in this comment box..

Comment: the whole view works fine. I have the problem when I try to get the "return price" as 50% of the JOBS.CALCULATED cost field.

Comment: Why use function `SUM()`. You need `CALCULATEDCOST/2` for current row of `jobs`, or the sum of a few rows, if so, what rows ?

Comment: where you have 'CASE WHEN @output > 0' they syntax looks wrong, there is no comma after the preceding sub-query and the sub query is not in brackets or aliased

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @output int
select @output= count (*) from jobcharge jobc inner join charge
         on charge.chargeid = jobc.chargeid
         where jobc.jobid = jobs.jobid and charge.description like '%return%'
CASE WHEN @output > 0 THEN SUM(JOBS.CALCULATEDCOST/2)
         ELSE '0.00' END as "RETURN PRICE",
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems incomplete query.
So i have assumed that there must be a table named "JOBS".
For that pl try following.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*)FROM JOBCHARGE JOBC
                INNER JOIN CHARGE ON CHARGE.CHARGEID = JOBC.CHARGEID
                WHERE JOBC.JOBID = JOBS.JOBID
                AND CHARGE.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%return%') > 0
          THEN
                SUM(JOBS.CALCULATEDCOST/2)
          ELSE '0.00'
    END as "RETURN PRICE"  FROM JOBS
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need the sum of several rows, but only one value ...

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
   select 1 from jobcharge jobc inner join charge
       ON charge.chargeid = jobc.chargeid
    WHERE jobc.jobid = jobs.jobid AND charge.description LIKE '%return%
) THEN jobs.CALCULATEDCOST/2 ELSE 0.00 END as "RETURN PRICE",
```

Use `exists (select 1 ...)` may by faster than `select count() ...`